# How often to randomize weights in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm implementing a multilayer perceptron and I'm playing around with some different features I heard about in class, one of which is periodically randomizing weights. My current approach is to randomize a small percentage of them once every few epochs, but it seems to be a fine line between randomizing enough to miss local minima and randomizing too much so that its hard to converge. Currently I'm running a 64, 30, 10 multilayer perceptron on a training set of about 4000 observations and randomizing .1% of the weights every 10 epochs.

Anyone have any input on a reasonable amount of randomization? Is that a good amount or should I be doing less? Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik noone is doing that nowadays (as you said - such thing requires arbitrarily fixing completely arbitrary numbers). There are plenty of techniques for making your learning better behaved - SGD (instead of full gradient); different kinds of normalization (like batch norm); momentum (thus Adam for example); dropout etc. do **not** add noise to weights, if you want to inject noise somewhere - inject it to samples, labels, but not into into weights (unless you keep the old ones in memory so you can backoff there is things go really wrong). Sensitivity of the network wrt. to weights is a complex, hard to model thing, which (in order to do well) would require things like computing full Fisher matrix etc. the benefits of such an approach are really minor as compared to computational (and implementation!) cost.